# Scrapy - missing html body

Tags: html, scrapy

Using scrapy some websites doesn't provide full html code, ie. https://www.amazon.de/Warner-Bros-5051891109537-GIOCO-MOVIE/dp/B00HR6RHBK

I try to get link to all offer-listings (https://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/B00HR6RHBK/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new)

Scrapy just cannot find it.

Trying:

> $ scrapy shell "https://www.amazon.de/Warner-Bros-5051891109537-GIOCO-MOVIE/dp/B00HR6RHBK"
>
> print(response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'new')]/@href"))

Result:

> []

Answer (score 1):

That link does not exist in the source of the page. So Scrapy can not find it. Try looking for /gp/offer-listing/B00HR6RHBK/ref=dp_olp_all_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=all and see if you can find that link

Comment: I can't if I try thru scrapy or wget, but I can when checking using Chrome/Firefox/etc. - is Splash a solution?